# Identify ram module linked to ECC error di DMESG

Tags: ram, dmesg, ecc

one of my server is logging the following ECC errors:

```
    [lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] {33}[Hardware Error]: Hardware error from APEI Generic Hardware Error 
Source: 1
    [lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] {33}[Hardware Error]: It has been corrected by h/w and requires no further action
    [lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] {33}[Hardware Error]: event severity: corrected
    [lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] {33}[Hardware Error]:  Error 0, type: corrected
    [lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] {33}[Hardware Error]:  fru_text: CorrectedErr
    [lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] {33}[Hardware Error]:   section_type: memory error
    [lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] {33}[Hardware Error]:   node: 0 device: 1
    [lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] {33}[Hardware Error]:   error_type: 2, single-bit ECC
    [lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] ghes_edac: Internal error: Can't find EDAC structure
```

The server has the following RAN configuration:

```
Handle 0x0029, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
        Maximum Capacity: 64 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0029
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM CHA3
        Bank Locator: BANK 0
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 2133 MHz
        Manufacturer: SK Hynix
        Serial Number: 71929DA0
        Asset Tag: 1651
        Part Number: HMA82GU7MFR8N-TF
        Rank: 2
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0029
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM CHA1
        Bank Locator: BANK 1
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 2133 MHz
        Manufacturer: SK Hynix
        Serial Number: 71929CFF
        Asset Tag: 1651
        Part Number: HMA82GU7MFR8N-TF
        Rank: 2
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0029
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM CHB4
        Bank Locator: BANK 2
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 2133 MHz
        Manufacturer: SK Hynix
        Serial Number: 71929BB8
        Asset Tag: 1651
        Part Number: HMA82GU7MFR8N-TF
        Rank: 2
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0029
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM CHB2
        Bank Locator: BANK 3
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 2133 MHz
        Manufacturer: Samsung
        Serial Number: 33BB5E37
        Asset Tag: 1641
        Part Number: M391A2K43BB1-CPB
        Rank: 2
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

How can I identify the faulty module to replace it? I think that the following log's row has the information I need but I miss the way to decrypt it.

```
[lun set 14 00:14:16 2020] {33}[Hardware Error]:   node: 0 device: 1
```